# Preloader with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

I have faced such a problem. I need to make a preloader with a percentage for a page but I don't know how. Actually, I don't need animation or simple preloader. What do I can and what do I have?

```
window.onload = function() {
var images = document.images,
    imagesTotalCount    = images.length,
    imagesLoadedCount   = 0,
    preloader           = document.getElementById('js_preloader'),
    percDisplay         = document.getElementById('js_preload__percentage');
for(var i = 0; i < imagesTotalCount; i++) {
    image_clone = new Image();
    image_clone.onload = image_loaded;
    image_clone.onerror = image_loaded;
    image_clone.src = images[i].src;
}
function image_loaded() {
    imagesTotalCount++;
    percDisplay.innerHTML = (((100 / imagesTotalCount) * imagesLoadedCount) << 0) + '%';
    if(imagesLoadedCount >= imagesTotalCount) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if(!preloader.classList.contains('done')) {
                preloader.classList.add('done');
            }
        }, 1500);
    }
}
```

};

This aproach allows to see all images to be downloaded and and calculate percentage. But how do I can also take in count the download of **css** and **js** files?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same approach, but with `document.scripts` and `document.styleSheets` collections.

Comment: Thank you very much, but can you advise about the exect code.
I mean 
style_clone = new Style();
script_clone = new Script ();
Or it shall be done via new Document ()?
Also what should I refer to src or href?
Sorry for may be obvious question but I am quite new to the sphere. Thank for patience )